# Running 3 consumers with one command in python kafka

Tags: python, apache-kafka

I have 3 consumers in my project
And I made three files for them const1.py const2.py const3.py
And to run them, I have to open three terminals and run the files
Can I define these three consumers in one file and run them with one command?

Answer (score 0):

You can use supervisord to run 3 python modules, or you can use one file and import `Thread` or `multiprocessing` modules to run all together after refactoring your code

Or use `nohup` to run each as a background daemon in one terminal, but still separate commands